# Why do the summary and class methods disagree on type in my data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

This is the setup:

```
mydf<-structure(list(weight = c(1.34288799762726, 1.18884372711182, 
1.15979790687561, 1.34288799762726, 1.08285343647003, 1.07932889461517, 
1.28913342952728, 1.211909532547, 1.03438591957092, 1.22719633579254
), RespID = c(3182, 3183, 3184, 3185, 3186, 3187, 3188, 3189, 
3190, 3191), b1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Mand", "Kvinde"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("weight", 
"RespID", "b1"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now a call to summary will generate the following output:

```
summary(mydf)
#     weight          RespID          b1   
# Min.   :1.034   Min.   :3182   Mand  :4  
# 1st Qu.:1.102   1st Qu.:3184   Kvinde:6  
# Median :1.200   Median :3186             
# Mean   :1.196   Mean   :3186             
# 3rd Qu.:1.274   3rd Qu.:3189             
# Max.   :1.343   Max.   :3191
```

Meanwhile apply gives another result:

```
apply(mydf, 2, class)
#     weight      RespID          b1 
#"character" "character" "character"
```

So according to apply each column in my data.frame is of class "character" which I know is wrong. Summary gets it right though.

Comment: The first sentence of `?apply` reads: "If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array." Matrices can only hold one data type.

Comment: apply is for arrays, not data.frames - this is probabably burns-faq no. 89383772

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `apply` expects a *matrix* and

```
> as.matrix(mydf)
   weight     RespID b1      
1  "1.342888" "3182" "Mand"  
2  "1.188844" "3183" "Kvinde"
3  "1.159798" "3184" "Mand"  
4  "1.342888" "3185" "Mand"  
5  "1.082853" "3186" "Kvinde"
6  "1.079329" "3187" "Kvinde"
7  "1.289133" "3188" "Mand"  
8  "1.211910" "3189" "Kvinde"
9  "1.034386" "3190" "Kvinde"
10 "1.227196" "3191" "Kvinde"
```

What you want to use is `sapply`:

```
> sapply(mydf,class)
   weight    RespID        b1 
"numeric" "numeric"  "factor"
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` coerces to a `matrix` which *cannot* contain a `factor` so it is coereced to a character variable:

```
df <- data.frame( x = as.factor(letters[1:3]) , y = as.factor(LETTERS[1:3]) )
str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ y: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3

apply(df,2,class)
          x           y 
"character" "character" 

 sapply(df,class)
       x        y 
"factor" "factor"
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the reason.

It seems like apply will coerce the data.frame to a matrix causing every column to be stored as a character type. The apply method will then of course report the classes after the convertion.. The trick is to realize that the data.frame is a glorified list and thus

```
lapply(mydf, class)
# $weight
# [1] "numeric"
# 
# $RespID 
# [1] "numeric"
# 
# $b1
# [1] "factor"
```

gives the right answer.

Comment: or, if you want a vector result instead of a list, `sapply(mydf, class)`